# The Temple of Puzzling

Tags: cipher, enigmatic-puzzle, story, visual, imgur-maze

<sub>Part of the [Community Metapuzzle](http://meta.puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/5588/community-metapuzzle), although it can be solved on it's own. The password in the puzzle below is also the word needed for the Metapuzzle. Link to the metapuzzle by [Deusovi](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/users/11876/deusovi) is [here](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/45927/community-metapuzzle-the-broken-time-machine).</sub>

---

Welcome **Indinana Bones** to your  first quest. To unlock the next quest, you must take the sacred **Golden Statue of Puzzling** from the temple.

You must also find a **hidden code** which will act as a password in the next quest.

If you wish to accept this quest, then click below to start your adventure...

[image]

Good luck explorer. You're going to need it.

---

<sub>This puzzle is inspired by the film [Indiana Jones - Raiders of the Lost Ark](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Raiders_of_the_Lost_Ark). **Knowledge of the film *is* required** but you only need to watch the first 10 minutes. All the information you need can be read [here](http://www.shmoop.com/raiders-of-the-lost-ark/scene-2-summary.html). Apologies for any mistakes or typos, I was running out of time towards the end so couldn't do a thorough check.</sub>

---

<sub>EDIT:</sub>

Despite double checking, it seems I made a mistake. 'x' should be 'z'. You'll know where when you get to it. Sorry for the delay and the inconvenience.

Comment: Ack, the youtube video is gone. I'll try and find another

Comment: In the first puzzle scene take note of the pigpen shapes in the NE and SW corners and also the 1 and 9 that are in there for some reason. Also, in that scene for the second, third, fourth and fifth ring the N is oriented facing inwards (position of the dot)

Comment: @boboquack It's not a 9. It's 19 (and 23) - it's telling (I think) in effect that dots come before 'non-dots' alphabetically

Comment: @Strawberry I realise that answer, I was collaborating with Desuvoi earlier this UTC day.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

(Don't worry, I haven't been spoiled for this! I just know the final passcode and that's it.)

After a few story images, we get to this:

[image]

> There seems to be a key to the cipher hidden in the stone - it's a variant of pigpen. If the numbers are to be trusted, it means that dots come before non-dotted shapes. That means the top left corner DOTTED is A, not the undotted top left as it would be in the standard pigpen cipher.
>  Using the pattern:
>  `[.] [ ]  [.][ ]`
>  `ABC JKL`
>  `DEF MNO  ST  WX`
>  `GHI PQR  UV  YZ`
>  and reading around the loops clockwise from the north gives us:
>
> ```
>  outer loop: REGA[l]R?D
>  ----------- EA?C[k]HOB
>  ----------- STAC[B]LE?
>  ----------- METI[c]?CU
>  inner loop: L?OU[H]SLY
> ```
>
> The fourth column has helpful arrows. I have indicated this with bracketed letters. The rest spell out the message "REGARD EACH OBSTACLE METICULOUSLY". Unfortunately, the fourth's columns don't seem to lead to any valid stack.imgur URLs in the indicated cases. In chat, however, Rubio found that reading them "upside down" (i.e. as you seem them) makes a valid url: https://i.stack.imgur.com/bGhQP.jpg

---

Now we have a branch!

> Each of the links in the previous image has one of the traps from the movie and a pigpen letter hidden inside:
>  The first room, the pit, has a `K`.
>  The second room, the spiders, has an `x`.
>  The third room, the boulder, has a `c`.
>  The fourth room, the spike gate, has an `H`.
>  The fifth room, the pressure plates, has a `T`.
>  Putting these all together in movie order (spiders-spikes-pit-plates-boulder) gives https://i.stack.imgur.com/xHKTc.jpg, which... doesn't seem to lead anywhere.

---

> BeastlyGerbil has clarified that it was meant to be a `z` in the spider room, not an `x`. Putting those together gives [image] along with a few more story images leading ultimately to this image:
>
>
>  [image]

That final image contains a code using the same method as the other codes we've seen so far. That code decodes to the password:

> **BIGFOOT**.

Comment: You have almost decided correctly but seem to have added some letters in. Should still be able to see the message

Comment: @Rubio finished it off. If you edit then I'll accept. Made a mistake with the spiders. It should have been a z not an x. Rest was fine

Answer (score 6):

Picking up where prior answer leaves off ....
OP made an error in one of the puzzle's images, making it unsolvable.

> In the second room, the spiders, the **x** was intended to decode as **z**.

Using that correction,

> and placing the traps in the order in which they appear in the movie, gives
>  [image]
>  which leads to more images, culminating with:
>  [image]
>  and more pigpen ciphers to decode.
>
>  These decode to **BIG FOOT**.

And that's the end of the line for this adventure.  Thanks to the other folks who helped on this, and the big nod to Deusovi for the heavy lifting getting us through the circles.